# Web server not directory to index.html in subdirectory

Tags: webserver, nginx

I have a weird problem with an nginx server I'm working on. I am trying to set up a small, static HTML web page in a sub directory. The server is working, as it's happily serving other sites (all of whcih are Wordpress based). The problem seems to be that when I add my content, for whatever reason I have to explicitly navigate to index.html, rather than having it redirect.

If I go to:

www.domain.example/subdirectory/index.html

I get the desired page.

However, if I call:

www.domain.example/subdirectory/

I get a Not Found error:

"Not Found

The requested URL /subdirectory/ was not found on this server."

Note that I don't have CPanel access to this server, and it's also running nginx. How can I make this redirect work correctly?

Comment: Check the nginx configuration. The default document name(s) can be set to any value. It's probably set to `index.php`.